# The Python script malfunctions with ReadTimeoutError ( Telegram bot + Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm trying to troubleshoot a python script implementing a Telegram bot functionality on a Raspberry Pi. ( https://www.instructables.com/Set-up-Telegram-Bot-on-Raspberry-Pi/ )

Here is the code, which has been borrowed from the above location and modified accordingly:

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
import time
import telepot

def handle (msg):
    chat_id = msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']

    print ('Got command: %s' % command )

    if command == '/arise_mainhost':
        os.system( 'wakeonlan <dest1_mac_address>' )
        bot.sendMessage( chat_id, 'Host ryzen.' )
    elif command == '/arise_memplace':
        os.system( 'wakeonlan <dest2_mac_address>' )
        bot.sendMessage( chat_id, 'Place ryzen.' )
    elif command == '/ismainhostasleep':
        status = os.system ( 'ping -c 1 <dest1_ip_address>' )
        if status == 0:
            bot.sendMessage( chat_id, 'Host awake!' )
        else:
            bot.sendMessage( chat_id, 'Host asleep...' )
    elif command == '/ismemplaceasleep':
        status = os.system ( 'ping -c 1 <dest2_ip_address>' )
        if status == 0:
            bot.sendMessage( chat_id, 'Place awake!' )
        else:
            bot.sendMessage( chat_id, 'Place asleep...' )

bot = telepot.Bot('<bot_token_id>')

#try:
bot.message_loop( handle )
# except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
#   print("Sth goes wrong")
print ('I am listening ...')

while 1:
        time.sleep(10)
```

And here are the exceptions/error I get

```
pi@raspi:~/telepot $ python3 lili.py

> I am listening ...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1012, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.timeout: _ssl.c:1106: The handshake operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 1181, in get_from_telegram_server
    result = self.getUpdates(offset=offset,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 1000, in getUpdates
    return self._api_request('getUpdates', _rectify(p))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 491, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/api.py", line 154, in request
    r = fn(*args, **kwargs)  # `fn` must be thread-safe
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 385, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 336, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=50)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1012, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.timeout: _ssl.c:1106: The handshake operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 1181, in get_from_telegram_server
    result = self.getUpdates(offset=offset,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 1000, in getUpdates
    return self._api_request('getUpdates', _rectify(p))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 491, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/api.py", line 154, in request
    r = fn(*args, **kwargs)  # `fn` must be thread-safe
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 385, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 336, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=50)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1012, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.timeout: _ssl.c:1106: The handshake operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 1181, in get_from_telegram_server
    result = self.getUpdates(offset=offset,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 1000, in getUpdates
    return self._api_request('getUpdates', _rectify(p))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 491, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/api.py", line 154, in request
    r = fn(*args, **kwargs)  # `fn` must be thread-safe
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 385, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 336, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=50)


> Got command: /arise_mainhost Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9
> with <dest1_mac_address>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1012, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.timeout: _ssl.c:1106: The handshake operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 1158, in collector
    callback(item)
  File "/home/krit/telebot/lili.py", line 18, in handle
    bot.sendMessage( chat_id, 'Host ryzen.' )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 513, in sendMessage
    return self._api_request('sendMessage', _rectify(p))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 491, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/api.py", line 154, in request
    r = fn(*args, **kwargs)  # `fn` must be thread-safe
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 385, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 336, in _raise_timeout
    raise ReadTimeoutError(
urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)


> Got command: /arise_memplace Sending magic packet to 255.255.255.255:9
> with <dest2_mac_address>


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 382, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1012, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 411, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 449, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
socket.timeout: _ssl.c:1106: The handshake operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 1158, in collector
    callback(item)
  File "/home/krit/telebot/lili.py", line 21, in handle
    bot.sendMessage( chat_id, 'Place ryzen.' )
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 513, in sendMessage
    return self._api_request('sendMessage', _rectify(p))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/__init__.py", line 491, in _api_request
    return api.request((self._token, method, params, files), **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/telepot/api.py", line 154, in request
    r = fn(*args, **kwargs)  # `fn` must be thread-safe
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 755, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 532, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 719, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 699, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 385, in _make_request
    self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)

  

> File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 336, in _raise_timeout
>     raise ReadTimeoutError( urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=30)
> 
> Got command: /ismainhostasleep
> PING <dest1_ip_address> (<dest1_ip_address>) 56(84) bytes of data. 64 bytes from <dest1_ip_address>: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.664 ms
> --- <dest_ip_address> ping statistics --- 1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.664/0.664/0.664/0.000 ms

.
.
( continues )
```

From the above trace, let's focus on the sections marked with "**>**". They are the sections of the script that are actually executed, as well as the `ReadTimeoutError` at the end. Regarding the error, I've tried a telnet from the pi to the mentioned destination and it is successful.

```
pi@raspi:~/telepot $ telnet api.telegram.org 443
Trying 2001:67c:4e8:f004::9...
Connected to api.telegram.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Thus, it is somehow unclarified why this error occurs, and I think this is the root of the issue.

The problem is that pi cannot keep this script running indefinitely.The bot commands are executed after a few minutes of delay, and the script eventually crashes.

As I'm not experienced with Python, any hints that I should focus on in the troubleshooting process are warmly welcome.

Versions currently in use

11 (bullseye) on the Raspberry Pi 3

Python 3.9.2

P.S. The script had been working properly for a couple of years in Raspbian 8 Jessie with Python 2.7.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Update: I think that the python version might cause the issue. In Python 3.9.2, it seems that I have to adjust to async telepot version, according to the below:

https://telepot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html

Comment: Update 2: tested on another terminal and site, again with Python 3.9.2, and it functioned properly.

Thus, troubleshoot goes back to the above traceback messages: 
"The handshake operation timed out"
"HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.telegram.org', port=443): Read timed out."

Comment: Update 3: After many failed, attempts, I ve switched the pi internet connection from home to 4g via mobile and the script responded as it should without exceptions.

Yet, I cannot locate what causes the issue in my home network. Checked the home router settings and they are the default ones, just like when this communication was functioning until a few months ago.

Anyone, any ideas?